# why backtracking does / does not happen (ending search with false or not)?

Tags: prolog, backtracking

This is a question asking why backtracking happens in one simple program and not another.

**Example 1.**

```
% water/2 relates temperature to state
water(Temp, solid) :- Temp =< 0.
water(Temp, liquid) :- Temp > 0, Temp < 100.
water(Temp, gas) :- Temp >= 100.

?- water(50,X).

X = liquid
false
```

**Example 2.**

```
% parent facts
parent(john, jane).
parent(john, james).
parent(sally, jane).
parent(martha, sally).

?- parent(X, jane).
X = john
X = sally
```

In example 1, prolog finds `X=liquid` as one solution, then prompts to search for more solutions. When none are found it returns **false**.

In example 2, prolog correctly finds `X=john`, prompts to continue the search, and then finds `X=sally`, but then does not prompt to continue searching. It does not finish with a **false** to indicate it tried the remaining rules (eg `parent(martha,sally)` the last rule) and failed.

**Question:** Why does the first example finish with a false, but the second does not?

Comment: The example 2 is most certainly SWI which indexes on both arguments. Example 1 is just the common way to do it. In any case: Do use a better [tag:prolog-toplevel] like that of Scryer. It will help you to better see also more complex cases.

Comment: hi @false yes this is SWI-prolog. Do different implementations differ in this behaviour? By the way I thought it might be indexing so I tried to introduce variables eg parent(X,Y): X=John, Y=Jane in an attempt to avoid that optimisation but that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to rewrite the facts to `parent(X,Y) :- mytrue, X = john,   Y = jane.` to prevent indexing in SWI. Yes, implementations differ here. SWI's implementation is quite advanced, but sometimes also unreliable. In any case as a beginner, simply ignore the `; false` this is valuable information for highly optimized code only.

Comment: hi @false if you want to write that as an answer,  I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: [Here in the SWI Prolog docs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary) under "Indexing" which links to [this page on SWI's indexing strategies](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a rule which disallows water to be in more than one state. There's several methods (mostly using e.g. cut), here's one:

```
water_temp_state(Temp, State) :-
    (   Temp =< 0 -> State = solid
    ;   Temp < 100 -> State = liquid
    ;   State = gas
    ).
```

Results:

```
?- water_temp_state(-5, S).
S = solid.

?- water_temp_state(5, S).
S = liquid.

?- water_temp_state(500, S).
S = gas.
```

Use multiple predicates when there is an actual *possibility* of multiple states.

Here's another method, just for fun:

```
water_state_comparison(solid, =<, 0).
water_state_comparison(liquid, <, 100).
water_state_comparison(gas, >=, 100).

water_temp_state_compare(Temp, State) :-
    water_state_comparison(State, Comp, Num),
    Pred =.. [Comp, Temp, Num],
    call(Pred),
    !.
```

... with same results.

Comment: hi @brebs .. I don't recognise your first code block as prolog. Is it? And your point about using predicates when there is a possibility of multiple states (ie not mutually exclusive) is interesting and not one I've read anywhere else.

Comment: @Penelope It is Prolog; see [Control Predicates (->/2) if/then/else](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) in the SWI Prolog documentation.